# how to find the last occurrence of ',' in a string in c# using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

how to find the last occurrence of ',' in a string in c# using RegEx

i have tried below code

```
string ss = Regex.Replace(strQuery, @"/\,(?<firstMatch>.*)=case(?<secondMatch>.*end\b)", @" case ${secondMatch} ""${firstMatch}"" ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

input

```
 SELECT  * FROM (select  TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Region_desc) as ROW_NUM,* from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Region_desc desc) as gridviewcount from( SELECT BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_ID,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_CODE,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_DESC,STATUS=CASE WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='I' THEN 'INACTIVE' ELSE '' END,
```

i am getting output

```
SELECT * FROM (select TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Region_desc) as ROW_NUM,* from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Region_desc desc) as gridviewcount from( SELECT BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_ID,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_CODE,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_DESC,STATUS=CASE WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='I' THEN 'INACTIVE' ELSE '' END,
```

but i need output like below

```
 SELECT  * FROM (select  TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Region_desc) as ROW_NUM,* from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Region_desc desc) as gridviewcount from( SELECT BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_ID,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_CODE,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_DESC,CASE WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='I' THEN 'INACTIVE' ELSE '' END "STATUS",
```

Comment: Do you really need to overcomplicate it using a RegEx? There is a perfectly fine method for doing this: [LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0w96zd3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: but there is a comma at the last.

Comment: You do not need a RegEx to find index of last occurence of something, you can use `String.LastIndexOf`

Comment: i need to use regex because input may differ

Comment: @nvoigt he also wants to fetch the part before `=case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the match with `$2 $1,`

```
(?i).*,([^=]*)=(CASE.*),
```

OR

```
(?i).*,([^=]*)=(CASE.*end)\b
```

Add case insensitive modifier `(?i)` at the start if you want to do a case insensitive match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yN7mR6/6)

```
string ss = Regex.Replace(strQuery, @".*,([^=]*)=(CASE.*end)\b",  "$2 $1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yN7mR6/7)

**Update:**

```
(?i)(.*,)([^=]*)=(CASE.*end)\b
```

Replacement string:

```
$1$3 "$2"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yN7mR6/8)

Comment: can you help to do if i need like this output...   SELECT  * FROM (select  TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Region_desc) as ROW_NUM,* from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Region_desc desc) as gridviewcount from( SELECT BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_ID,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_CODE,BO_REGION_MASTER.Region_DESC,CASE WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='A' THEN 'ACTIVE' WHEN BO_REGION_MASTER.STATUS='I' THEN 'INACTIVE' ELSE '' END STATUS,